# Resolve $\cos(3x)= \cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to solve $$\cos(3x)= \cos(2x)$$

I found how to express both of them for $x$ only and now I have
$$4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

What do I do now?

Comment: my hint: $\cos A=\cos B\iff A=B$

Answer (score 17):

Notice, we have $$\cos(3x)=\cos(2x)$$ 
$$3x=2n\pi\pm 2x$$
Where, $n$ is any integer

Now, we have the following solutions

$$3x=2n\pi+2x\implies \color{red}{x=2n\pi}$$
or 
$$3x=2n\pi-2x\implies \color{red}{x=\frac{2n\pi}{5}}$$

Comment: I see that it works pretty well, thank you! But can you explain the +/- 2x?

Comment: Alright, we know that $\cos(2n\pi+\theta)=\cos(2n\pi-\theta)=\cos\theta$ Hence, the general solution of $\cos (3x)=\cos(2x)$ is $3x=2n\pi\pm 2x$

Comment: It appears that your first family of solutions is a subset of your second family.

Answer (score 6):

We have the formula
$$ \cos{(a+b)}-\cos{(a-b)} = -2\sin{a}\sin{b}, $$
so if we put $a=5x/2,b=x/2$, we have
$$ 0 = \cos{3x}-\cos{2x} = -2\sin{\left(\frac{5}{2}x\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)},$$
so you just have to determine the $x$ for which either one of the sines is equal to $0$, which I'm sure you can do.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Use this result

$$\cos(a)=\cos(b)\iff a\equiv \pm b\pmod{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

You reached to the cubic equation $$4t^3-2t^2-3t+1=0$$ where $$t=\cos(x)\in [-1,1]$$

One root is $t=1$. Divide the polynomial by $(t-1)$ and find the other two roots. Finally plug in $t=\cos(x)$ to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $$\cos \alpha=\cos \beta$$$$\iff \alpha=2k\pi\pm \beta$$
where; $k=0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm 3, \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(3x)=\cos(2x)$$
$$\cos(3x)-\cos(2x)=0$$
$$2\sin(3x/2)\sin(-x/2)=0$$
$$-2\sin(3x/2)\sin(x/2)=0$$
$$\sin(3x/2)=0\implies 3x/2=k\pi\iff x=2k\pi/3$$
or $$\sin(x/2)=0\implies x/2=k\pi\iff x=2k\pi$$